# libcurl fails (response code 0 - host not found) in program (built with MinGW) if using bundled libcurl-4.dll

Tags: c++, curl, mingw, libcurl, msys2

I've ported an application over to windows using MinGW and want to distribute it with all the dlls it needs to run.

The app requires libcurl for some ssl (https) requests it makes.

To distribute it I copied all the .dlls & put them alongside the .exe.
That runs fine but whenever it attempts to make a request in curl it gets a 0 response (as in host not found - not zero okay).

The program works fine if I don't use my copy of libcurl-4.dll but instead use the one bundled with msys2.

Why does this happen? I checked in process explorer and the only difference between it working or not is if it uses my copy of libcurl-4.dll (all other dependencies of curl copied fine).

[image]

^ that's when it works (using git for window's .dll -- if I copied that dll to next to the program it'd fail)

Answer (score 0):

If your libcurl function invoke actually returns zero, then it was invoked fine and there's no problem with your DLLs or similar, but sounds like like you need to tweak your libcurl usage.

Comment: No the status code from any function http function is zero. Meaning host not found. I also don't use curl directly, I use it via cpr (a c++ wrapper).

Comment: It's not a linker problem it's linked fine. It's just simply seems like using a local copy of libcurl-4.dll means that my requests (which are using https) all fail with response code zero (host not found). It works fine if I delete my copy & let it link to the dll bundled with something like git for windows or msys2. I can only guess that there's some hidden config I'm missing or libcurl maybe somehow fails to dynamically load some other dlls that I can't see (though I'd doubt that looking at process explorer).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason but I don't know a decent solution.

The bundled `libcurl-4.dll` only works for https requests if you also bundle the ssl folder that contains certificates. I feel like this is something where it should be using the OS' certs (Windows) but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: cURL can be configured with different TLS backends. I suspect "your" DLL uses the OpenSSL backend, and what you probably want is the Schannel (WinSSL) backend.